# Convert MySQL query to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I need to convert this `MySQL` query to a `SQL Server` query where the syntax `'LIMIT ?, ?'` is my main main problem because isn't compatible with `SQL Server`.

At the same time I don't know the meaning of the clause at the end `SELECT FOUND_ROW()`.

I am beginner with databases so I would appreciate any assistance.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS TITLE, URL FROM SITE WHERE CITY='Berlin' LIMIT ?, ?

...

stmt.setInt(1, offset);
stmt.setInt(2, numRecords);

...

rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");
if (rs.next())
this.noOfRecords = rs.getInt(1);

...
```

Comment: is it a custom function FOUND_ROWS()

Comment: No, it is mysql function...

Comment: `FOUND_ROWS()` is a MySQL function. Documentation is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).

Comment: FOUND_ROWS() is not replicated reliably, and should not be used with databases that are to be replicated.

Answer (score 1):

If the MySQL is:

```
SELECT URL
  FROM SITE
  WHERE CITY='Berlin'
  LIMIT 30, 20
```

Then it's returning rows 31 through 50. In SQL Server you can do something like this:

```
WITH somerows AS (
  SELECT TOP 50 URL, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY URL) AS SeqValue
  FROM SITE
  WHERE CITY='Berlin'
)
SELECT * FROM somerows
WHERE SeqValue BETWEEN 31 and 50
```

Note that the `50` in the SQL Server query is the sum of the MySQL `LIMIT` values, and that the `30` in MySQL is zero-indexed so it becomes `31` in SQL Server, where the `ROW_NUMBER` counter is one-indexed. Many thanks to Kevin Suchlicki for pointing this out in the comments below.

Also note that, unlike your MySQL query, you have to order the rows with the SQL Server query.

Finally, `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is a MySQL keyword that enables the `FOUND_ROWS()` function. It's explained in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows). There's no SQL Server equivalent. You'll need to count the rows some other way to set `this.noOfRecords` in your code, but you should be able to work around that.

Comment: Ed Gibbs' answer is mostly right.  Slight corrections: the second parameter in the MySQL LIMIT clause is the *count* of records to display, and the first parameter is zero-based.  So the equivalent LIMIT parameters to Ed's TSQL syntax are LIMIT 40, 10

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @KevinSuchlicki, I muffed that one! I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question marks are used in MySQL to bind parameters to a statement. So based on your code, the parameters being passed are the offset and number or records to be used by the LIMIT function. Seems to me that it's paging the results. Try this SQL on your SQL Server statement as replacement of the MySQL

```
DECLARE @offset INT
DECLARE @numRecords INT
SET @offset = 1
SET @numRecords = 2

SET ROWCOUNT @numRecords
WITH RowsResult AS 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TITLE) AS RowNum,
        TITLE, 
        URL 
    FROM [SITE] 
    WHERE CITY='Berlin' 
    ORDER BY TITLE
)
SELECT  TITLE
FROM    URL
WHERE   RowNum > @offset
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```